# Multiple build.gradle files in Android Studio

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I'm just getting use to Gradle and Android Studio. I notice that Android Studio projects can have multiple build.gradle files. There is one located in the project's root folder and there's a second one located in the project's app folder. Can someone explain what the purpose of having these two are? When I do a build in AS, are both used or just one of them (and if only one of them, which one)?

Comment: Good question, especially as the documentation only mentions one (and seems to have the directories confused).  See: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your project contains multiple modules, you may use the root (project-level) build.gradle file to keep configuration common to all modules. E.g. you may put common dependencies there.

Default top-level build.gradle for Android Studio has "allprojects" block in the top-level build.gradle that adds "jcenter" repository to every module.

Comment: For additional information, see the "multi-project builds" chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Comment: Is there a particular order in which these build files get executed?

Comment: My understanding of Gradle is that these scripts configure the build model, e.g. they run before the build and set attributes on objects and then Gradle does the build based on that configuration. You can play with adding "println" statements into your scripts to better understand the order. Note how some code (e.g. "allprojects" block from the top-level build.gradle) are executed multiple times.